# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in on line 24

Tags: json, pdo

Quiero pasar los resultados de las dos consultas en una misma variable para que me lo muestre en una tabla, pero me arroja ese error en el código, el código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
include("../BD-Config/config.php");
session_start();
// liste des événements
 $json = array();
 // requête qui récupère les événements
 $requete = "SELECT * FROM evenement JOIN mis_contactos JOIN vehiculos
            ON id_mec = id_meca AND id_usuario = id_user JOIN empresa WHERE evenement.id_user=1 AND empresa.id_meca=evenement.id_mec AND
                evenement.id_vehiculo = vehiculos.id_vehiculo AND evenement.estado_cita>0 AND evenement.estado_cita<6 ORDER BY id DESC";

$querreque = "SELECT * FROM cita_autolavado JOIN vehiculos JOIN empresa WHERE id_user = 1 AND vehiculos.id_vehiculo = cita_autolavado.id_vehiculo AND id_meca = cita_autolavado.id_mec";


 // connexion à la base de données
 try { 
 $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servidor."; dbname=".$bd."; charset=utf8", $usuario, $pass);
 } catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('No se Pudo Conectar.');
 }
 // exécution de la requête
 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
 $risultato = $bdd->query($querreque) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

$resulteichon = $risultato.$resultat;
 //print_r($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
 // envoi du résultat au success
 echo json_encode($resulteichon->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

La línea

```
$resulteichon = $risultato.$resultat;
```

Se debe reemplazar por

```
$resulteichon = print_r($risultato, true).print_r($resultat, true);
```

Lo que hace la función `print_r()` es convertir un objeto PHP a un string (cadena de caracteres) que se puede concatenar. El valor `true` en el segundo argumento es para que la función devuelva el string en lugar de imprimirlo en la consola.

Answer (score 1):

El error proviene de esta línea:

```
$resulteichon = $risultato.$resultat;
```

Las variables `$risultato` y `$resultat` son objetos de la clase `PDOStatement` y no puedes concatenarlos como si fueran `string`.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo pero no se que hacer para poder concatenar o mandar las variables para imprimirlos en la tabla

Comment: ¿No existe la posibilidad de hacer una consulta con todos esos datos que haces en dos consultas diferentes? De lo contrario, va a ser complicado hacerlo por separado, y querer juntarlos después.

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no he podido realizar esa consulta en una sola, fue mi primer opción desde un principio